# Computed column expression in 2 tables

Tags: sql, command, calculated-columns

I have a product table and a detail table

**Product**

```
ID int
Price int
```

**Detail**

```
ID int
Quantity int
Total int
```

I do the multiplication `Quantity * Price`, what is the SQL command to use? Thanks

**I USE THIS**

```
ALTER TABLE DETAIL
ADD Total AS Quantity * product.price where Detail.ID = Product.ID
```

Comment: what field are these tables joined on?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not very clear on what database system you use - and these kind of things are very vendor-specific.

If you're using SQL Server, the answer is simple: you **cannot** do this.

The computed column **cannot** reference another table - only constants, columns from that same table - or stored functions.

Now you *might* be able to create a stored function that would go grab that data from the other table - I would **NOT** do it. Putting data access into stored functions is a sure recipe for performance disasters - just don't do it!

The solution here would probably be a **view** across the two tables that would do the calculation

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ProductAndDetail 
AS
   SELECT
       p.ID, p.Price,
       d.Quantity,  
       Total = ISNULL(d.Quantity, 0) * ISNULL(p.Price, 0.0)
   FROM
       dbo.Product p
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.Detail d ON p.ID = d.ID
```

Then you can select from this new view:

```
SELECT ID, Price, Quantity, Total
FROM dbo.ProductAndDetail
```

and the `Total` is calculated "on the fly" for each row

**Update:** ah - okay, it seems you need a static data set for reporting - in that case, you can do the following:

```
   SELECT
       p.ID, p.Price,
       d.Quantity,  
       Total = ISNULL(d.Quantity, 0) * ISNULL(p.Price, 0.0)
   INTO
       dbo.ProductAndDetailsForReporting
   FROM
       dbo.Product p
   INNER JOIN
       dbo.Detail d ON p.ID = d.ID
```

Then you get a new table `dbo.ProductAndDetailsForReporting` that contains all rows from `Product` and `Detail` and the calculated `Total` column. Now run your reports on that table - it will **not change** unless you change something yourself (unlike the view, which is always updated).

Comment: I copied your code, when I insert data in my view says that the value Total can not be null

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to make sure that the calculation is continued in sight? for example, if the total exchange amount does not change. in essence is read-only. You can?

Comment: For example, if I change the price of a product, I do not want to be the total ricolacolato. There is no way to put the total field as readonly?

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: no you cannot do this. The view will always calculate that `Total` every time you query it.

Comment: Now I really have no more ideas. Unfortunately, in my scenario I have to make annual reports, and employee salaries must be increased later, but the total cost of each employee must not be changed. I looked everywhere, but nobody has come across in my situation: (

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: sounds you would have to do a `SELECT` across both tables and store the results into a temporary table that you then use for the reporting and all.

Comment: Yes it can be a good idea. In this case I should not even use views, right? The only thing I have to do is create a third table for example TotoalDetail with ID, ProductID, DetailID and total field, right? Make sure that when entering the value is stored in that table, but how do I make this field readonly?

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: yes exactly. Information like that (that you need it for reporting and you need a "static" set of data) would be most important - you should have mentioned that in your question - that would have made answering your question a lot easier!

Comment: Make sure that when entering the value is stored in that table, but how do I make this field readonly?

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: you cannot. Just **don't** update that table! Just use it for reporting and nothing else - fill it, create your reports from it - that's all.

Comment: Yes, but if for example the employee's salary increases, the total value change. Eventually my client wants to see the exact calculations. For this I needed to do this (they are two weeks I'm going crazy)

Comment: @MirkoPastorelli: once you have the data you want to report from in that table, you can update it if needed ......

Answer (score 0):

you code should be roughly as

```
employe.Quantity * product.price where empoye.ID=product.ID
```

that's an idea and should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT (Product.Price * Detail.Quantity) AS 'answer'
FROM Product
INNER JOIN Detail ON Product.ID = Detail.ID
WHERE Product.Price IS NOT NULL AND Detail.Quantity IS NOT NULL AND Product.Price != '' AND Detail.Quantity != ''
```

OR..

```
SELECT (Product.Price * Detail.Quantity) AS 'answer'
FROM Product
LEFT OUTER JOIN Detail ON Product.ID = Detail.ID
WHERE Product.Price IS NOT NULL AND Product.Price != ''
```

Comment: I need detail.id = product.id

Comment: The problem is that I do not have to do the queries .. but a calculated column

Comment: you won't be able to in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

You can only make computed column in a table based on other columns in the same table. If you want to achieve this you need to create a trigger that updates this value in a physical column (whereby the trigger can do the join). (Or you can create a view).